# How to check click on "Allow" option in runtime permissions

Tags: java, android, runtime-permissions

In my application I want to use `runtime permissions` for `Storage` and `Camera`.

For this, I've written below code and it works for me, but I want know if user clicks on "Allow" option or not.

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQ = 2008;
private static final int STORAGE_REQ = 2005;
@OnClick(R.id.newAddFrag_uploadImageRootLay)
void uploadImage() {
    new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .title("Select")
            .items(R.array.uploadImages)
            .titleGravity(GravityEnum.CENTER)
            .itemsGravity(GravityEnum.CENTER)
            .typeface("IranSans.ttf", "IranSans.ttf")
            .itemsIds(R.array.itemIds)
            .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            if (checkIfStorage(context)) {
                                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO);
                            } else {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_REQ);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (checkIfCamera(context)) {
                                captureImage();
                            } else {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_REQ);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            })
            .show();
}

private boolean checkIfCamera(Context context) {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean checkIfStorage(Context context) {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            newAddFrag_uploadImageRootLay.setEnabled(true);
            newAddFrag_uploadImageSuccessTxt.setEnabled(true);
            newAddFrag_uploadImageLay.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQ) {
        Log.e("permissionsLog", "CAMERA");
    }
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_REQ) {
        Log.e("permissionsLog", "STORAGE");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the values for `CAMERA_REQ` & `STORAGE_REQ`?

Comment: @Sagar, please see my update code

Comment: @Sagar, can you help me my friend?

Comment: Is the permission dialog shown?

Comment: @Sagar, yes Permission dialogs shown and when click on Allow i can open camera. but don't show me Log when click on Allow. please help me

Comment: @Sagar, can you help me my friend? are you here dear ?

Comment: can you put a breakpoint and check if `onRequestPermissionsResult` is called?

Comment: @Sagar, i check it. not call this!

Comment: are you executing this code in fragment?

Comment: Update your question with class statement

Comment: @Sagar, yes i write above codes into fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following rules are implied when are requesting permission:

- If you request permission in `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, you should simply call `requestPermissions` (since its already available in support lib).
- If you call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` in a fragment, then the `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback will be delivered to Activity and not the `Fragment`.

Since you are requesting permission in `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` either simply use `requestPermissions` or Override `onRequestPermissionsResult` in your `Activity` and handle the result there.

Comment: can you send to me code with my above codes? please

Comment: @Hock Just remove `ActivityCompat` from `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`

Comment: @Hock No problem. Enjoy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

When using the Support library, you have to use the correct method calls. For example:

- When in **AppCompatActivity**, you should use ActivityCompat.requestPermissions;
- When in **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**, you should use simply requestPermissions (this is an instance method of android.support.v4.app.Fragment)

If you call **ActivityCompat.requestPermissions** in a **fragment**, the **onRequestPermissionsResult** callback is called on the activity and not the fragment.

Hope explanation helps!

To get more knowledge read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java).

Comment: how can i use this into this fragment? i want call into fragment

Comment: When using Fragment, you should use simply requestPermissions (this is an instance method of android.support.v4.app.Fragment)

Comment: can you send to me code with my above codes? please

Comment: requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_REQ)

Comment: Thanks dear firend